# Прижать картинку к верху страницы

Tags: html, css, jpeg

Как можно в HTML и CSS прижать картинку строго к верху страницы, чтобы она прям прилипала? Имеется такой код:

```
<style>
        .top {
            top: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <img id="top" src="elem.jpg" align="center" width="1200px">
    </body>
```

После этого надо оставить все таким образом, чтобы картинка оставалась по центру.

Comment: при скролинге, что должно происходить с изображением?

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.b{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.b img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
     .top-line {
       position:absolute;
       top:0px;
     }
</style>

<body>
    <img id="top-line" src="elem.jpg" align="center" width="1200px">
</body>
```

Учтите, что позиционирование `position:absolute;` отразится на других элементах - они будут вести себя так, словно абсолютно-позиционированного элемента не существует на странице.